# Jboss clustering in Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, cluster, jboss, amazon-web-services

I am working to put an application that would require scalability on Amazon EC2 but this is new to me. I started reading on jboss clustering and how to create new nodes with multi-casting.

While reading about Amazon EC2 and its Auto Scaling feature, I am little confused and not able to figure out whether there is a need for handling Jboss clustering for hosting an application on EC2, as EC2's load balancer takes care of creating an extra instance and managing the requests as configured.

Any help and pointers in this area would be useful.

Comment: Hi user73430.  Do you need any "native" JBoss clustering features, like shared session state, or anything like that?  Or is a simple HTTP load balancer good enough?

Comment: Yes. I do need native Jboss clustering features like shared session state.

Answer (score 2):

You can use CloudWatch (metrics and monitoring aws service) to automatically trigger the start of a new jboss application server. Once the load begins to decrease you can use the same metrics to scale down your application server group. The instance you decide to use for the auto scaling feature needs to boot and start the service with no manual intervention.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the clustered Elastic Beanstalk only supports the standard Tomcat container. JBoss and Liferay, for example, are still , as of yet, unsupported container types. You can do metrics on your own EC2 instance that has JBoss, but the complexity of setting up the auto-scaling, in that type of configuration would be FAR more difficult:  you would have to build your EC2 instance to auto-load it's stack and combine in the cluster if they were auto-started.